# Is there a maven plugin that runs acceptance/e2e tests?

Tags: maven, selenium, maven-plugin, e2e-testing

Maven has:

- Surefire plugin that runs unit tests
- Failsafe plugin that runs integration tests

I've got some automated UI E2E tests written in Selenium that i would like to run using a Maven plugin.

Comment: Selenium tests are usually integration test which should be run by maven-failsafe-plugin (bound to integration-test phase)...

Comment: i see. So selenium tests should not be used for acceptance/e2e tests?

Comment: I think selenium tests work fine as acceptance/e2e tests. They are also integration tests.

Comment: after some reading, yeah i now understand acceptance/e2e also are integration tests. i think they are subset of "integration tests" because they are integrating 'End to End' - so yeah i see your point. Thanks. That cleared me up on test definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Would the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) work?

Comment: @khmarbaise please explain

Comment: Those tests are already written as Tests so it makes more sense to use maven-failsafe-plugin instead....

Comment: Not sure about this exec maven plugin. But after more research i think it is possible to do with maven-failsafe-plugin. Going to give that a try next